# FullCalendar Scheduler Events are not showing in TimelineView

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have created a scheduler with following events and resources

```
var sampleEvents = [{   'id': '1',
                        'resourceid': '27', 
                        'start': '2018-09-19T07:00:00',
                        'stop': '2018-09-19T16:00:00',
                        'title': 'Message 1',
                    }];

var sampleResources = [{
                        facility_type: "Message Type", 
                        id: '27', 
                        title: "Message 1"
                      }];

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                                schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
                                now: currenDate //Today's Date,
                                editable: false,
                                header: {
                                  left: 'today prev,next',
                                  center: 'title',
                                  right: 'month,timelineDay,agendaWeek'
                                },
                                defaultView: 'month',
                                resourceGroupField: 'facility_type',
                                resourceColumns: [
                                    {
                                        labelText: 'Facility',
                                        field: 'title',
                                        width: 150,
                                    },
                                ],
                                resources: sampleEvents,
                                events: sampleResources,
                                dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                                  if(view.name == 'month' || view.name == 'basicWeek') {
                                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'timelineDay');
                                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
                                  }
                                },
                              });

                            }, function (error) {

                        });
```

The events are showing in month view, but they are not shown in day view. Can someone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried by removing the `defaultView` option?

Comment: In the first variable   'title': 'Message 1', was ended with comma(,) . Remove that additional comma(,) .

Comment: @Suresh in JS that doesn't invalidate the object. It does not result in a syntax error. You can test that for yourself very quickly and easily. Anyway, how is it relevant to what was being asked, in your opinion?

Comment: @ArunKumar why? All that does is change which view is displayed when the calendar loads. It doesn't affect the _behaviour_ of any view, which is what is being asked about.

Comment: We are passing sampleEvents  to the fullCalendar initialization. If any thing wrong in passed parameters then there might be a chance of miscellaneous behavior right. As

Comment: It is not caseSensitive. Your solution will not resolve the issue @erarslan solution will resolve the issue. For your reference check the working link http://jsfiddle.net/jso51pm6/3769/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, variable and property names are case-sensitive. Therefore

```
'resourceid': '27'`
```

should be

```
'resourceId': '27'
```

as [per the example in the documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-and-events). The event isn't showing the timeline view because as far as fullCalendar is concerned you didn't tell it which resource to associate it with.

Answer (score 1):

Assigned objects are improper. If you pass the correct objects. It will work fine

```
resources: sampleResources,
 events: sampleEvents
```

You can refer below working jsfiddle link

```
http://jsfiddle.net/jso51pm6/3769/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                            resources: sampleEvents,
                            events: sampleResources,
```

You filled them wrong. Switch them. It will work.

```
                            resources: sampleResources,
                            events: sampleEvents,
```